# Curvature of a non-compact complete surface

Tags: differential-geometry, curvature

Assume $\Sigma$ is a non compact, complete surface. Assume the integral $$\int_{\Sigma}K$$ is convergent, where K is the Gauss curvature of $\Sigma$. Is it always true that $$\frac{1}{2\pi}\int_{\Sigma}K$$ is an integer?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No. Start with a one-nappe circular cone. Cut off the tip and replace with a subset of a sphere, resulting in what is now a $C^1$ infinite surface. Smooth near the circle where they join, so the result is at least $C^2.$ The result has zero curvature except near the spherical part. Since we did not specify the central angle of the cone, we get whatever we like in the way of total Gauss curvature, up to an effective maximum given by a hemisphere and an infinite cylinder.

Comment: Better make it $C^2$ so that $K$ makes sense. This smoothing idea also shows how to "fix" Gauss-Bonnet when you have some cone points in a compact surface.

Comment: Do you know where I could find more information about a $C^1$ infinite surface?

Comment: Im sorry so this $C^1$ infinite surface is similar to what you would get by intersecting a sphere with two parallel planes? Or is that incorrect?

Comment: @user77680, what is your actual background?

Comment: @user, it resembles a badminton birdie, where you let the part with the feathers just keep going and going.

Comment: Double bachelors physics and pure math and Masters in applied math but I've never talked about any of these things.

Comment: ohhhhhh ok I see what you are saying now replace what was cut off with the subset of the sphere. That visual helped a lot. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

Better luck on this for complete *minimal surfaces.* In that case, $K$ can't change sign and complex variable theory tells you the Gauss map can't miss many values.

Answer (score 0):

I believe that [Alexander horned sphere](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alexander_horned_sphere) is a good example for as a visual representation for as an answer.

Comment: Could you add some more details to your answer? Else it is best to leave this as a comment.

Answer (score 0):

Sure, I am going to have to go with the contrapositive on this one: $\int{\Sigma}$div$\gamma$$\nu$ = $\int{\partial\Sigma}< \nu, N> \sigma$ #. In other words Stokes theorem.